# Rename directory contents in OSX terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have multiple folders with similarly named files (e.g., `Article(1).rtf`, `Article(2).rtf`, etc.). I want to store them all in a single directory, but since they have exactly the same name, they are immediately overwritten. I would like to add, for example, a different number to the name of each file depending on the folder they're in, so that the names are different. E.g., `Article(1)1.rtf`, `Article(2)1.rtf` for the first folder, `Article(1)2.rtf`, `Article(2)2.rtf` for the second, etc. How would I go by it in Terminal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `mv` from GNU Coreutils

One way to do this is with the `mv` utility from GNU coreutils. You can install it via Homebrew with:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Once you have the utilities installed, you can use GNU version of `mv`, which Homebrew makes available as `gmv` to avoid conflicts with the native BSD version. The GNU version has a very handy `--backup` flag, which is ideal for this use case. For example:

```
find . -name '*rtf' \
       -exec gmv --backup=numbered {} /path/to/merge/directory/ +
```

This will prevent clobbering of files, and results in versioned filenames like:

- Article(1).rtf
- Article(1).rtf~1
- Article(1).rtf~2
- Article(2).rtf
- Article(2).rtf~1
- Article(2).rtf~2

and so forth. You can then use other Homebrew-installable utilities like `fdupes` to deduplicate or `rename` to further munge the filenames to suit your purposes.